# Symfony 2.8 custom authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I need custom Form Login authentication with a third party web service. The problem is that i can't implement `UserProvider's` method `loadUserByUsername($username)`. Also symfony calls `refreshUser(UserInterface $user)` on every page load which calls the `loadUserByUsername`.. My service has only one method that accepts username and password and returns success if they are valid otherwise false. Can i ignore the UserProvider and everything related to it??? Any suggestions.

Comment: No you cannot ignore user provider however take a look at the guard component. http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html Should be fairly easy to implement your own authenticator.

Comment: Why "can't" you implement `loadUserByUsername($username)` ? You are free to implement it as you which as well as `refreshUser(UserInterface $user)`, using a caching service if required. Note the `$username` is just a keyword which actually means "whatever", you are free to provide whatever you need here to authenticate against your custom service as far as you respect the interface. And as @Cerad said, the new `GuardAuthenticator` are much simpler to work with.

Comment: @BorisGuéry - It is not so much that they can't implement loadUserByUsername but rather what they really want is a loadUserByUsernameAndPassword.  Which sadly does not exist.  I had the same question years ago.  And back then, implementing your own authenticator was far more challenging.

Comment: @Cerad, that's exactly what I wanted to point out. The purpose of the `$username` here is not to be provided an username as it is used in common username / password combination, but whatever you want to use as it. May it be an e-mail, a token, or even a combination of `username` and `password`. Either by providing a custom formatted string recognized by your provider, or by returning a generic / fake `User` implementation from which you can retrieve the `username` and use it when implementing the `AuthenticationProvider` or the newly `GuardAuthentication`.

Comment: I don't have access to users by email username or whatever else. I can't provide list of users from the web service so I see no sense of UserProvider. I created custom UserProvider with method loadUserByUsernameAndPassword($username, $password) but symfony calls refreshUser on every page load which calls my web service login function so i move auth login in custom Authenticator but symfony still calls refreshUser...

Comment: refreshUser only calls loadUser by default in case the user information has changed between requests.  In your implementation you can just have it return the current user.

Comment: YES after a few hours i realized that and now i have custom user provider with method loadUserByUsername($username) which is never executed and refreshUser(UserInterface $user) which does absolutely nothing just returns the same $user :D So i thought there may be option to skip the UserProvider